# XPath to be precised into one in order to extract text from a web page?

Tags: xpath

I have a few Xpaths as below:

```
//*[@id="904735f0-bb82-11ea-a473-6d0f51688222"]/div/p

//*[@id="729c0860-a71d-11ea-b994-53a3e91a35c2"]/div/div/div[1]/div/p

//*[@id="2555ab30-bb84-11ea-9e8b-277e7f6208b2"]/div/div/div[1]/div/p

//*[@id="7e100250-a71d-11ea-b994-53a3e91a35c2"]/div/div/div[1]/div/p

//*[@id="811727d0-a71d-11ea-b994-53a3e91a35c2"]/div/div/div[1]/div/p
```

All of the above are used to extract text from a single web page since text is located at different view--ports, but I wish to find a single xpath to extract text for all of them. Is it possible to use 'and' and multiple ID's to extract all of it through one xpath?

Any other suggestions would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `or` operator for the last four.
And the merge-nodes operator `|` to add the first one.

So to select all 5 expression in one, use the following expression:

```
//*[@id="904735f0-bb82-11ea-a473-6d0f51688222"]/div/p | //*[@id="729c0860-a71d-11ea-b994-53a3e91a35c2" or @id="2555ab30-bb84-11ea-9e8b-277e7f6208b2" or @id="7e100250-a71d-11ea-b994-53a3e91a35c2" or @id="811727d0-a71d-11ea-b994-53a3e91a35c2"]/div/div/div[1]/div/p
```

Comment: Superb. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

A shorter and more generic solution could be :

```
(//div/div/div[1]/div/p|//div/p)[parent::*[string-length(@id)=36 and substring(@id,24,1)="-"]]
```

First part with `()` is used to specify the end of the path. Since `@id` attributes have the same length, we use it inside the predicate. We also verify the presence of a `-` at a specific position with `substring`.